# In the windows 10 search bar, how can I get internet searches to open up in my default browser instead of Edge?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, search, microsoft-edge

Just installed Windows 10 so I'm all new to this operating system, I notice that when I do a search in the "Search the web and Windows" field in the start menu, it always opens up Edge even through I've installed Chrome and set it as the default browser.

How can I get my internet searches to open up in Chrome instead?

Comment: Windows 10 seems to ignore any "set as default program" requests issued by programs themselves (E.g from within Chrome.) You have to manually set the default program through the settings app as described in the answer given by Rakitić below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of April 28th 2016, all web searches in Cortana will open in Edge and use Bing as the search engine regardless of any defaults you have set. These options have been hard-coded into Cortana, and as far as I know, there are no ways around this without using a 3rd party application to redirect the requests.

"Starting today, to ensure we can deliver the integrated search experience designed for Windows 10, Microsoft Edge will be the only browser that will launch when you search from the Cortana box."

Source:
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/28/delivering-personalized-search-experiences-in-windows-10-through-cortana/

Comment: Can you provide a source to confirm this?

Comment: wow, well that's just terrible. That basically means I won't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open the Start menu and click "**Settings**".
- On the "**System**" screen, click "**Default apps**" in the list of items on the left.
- Scroll down to the "**Web Browser**" section and click on "**Microsoft Edge**" *(by default it is set to Microsoft Edge)* and choose from the Default Browser Options you get after clicking.
- Now, you can set your Default Web Browser to "**Google Chrome**" or whichever you feel like.

[image: search_chrome]

Comment: This question is about searching from the windows start menu, which is fundamentally different than the default browser.